Local crate is unresolved inside project even after adding it to `Cargo.toml`
I am working on creating a crate that is just a FFI to the opus audio codec. (I called it opus_ffi.) I want to add it as a local dependency inside of the project. However, when I try and use it, I get an failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module opus_ffi use of undeclared crate or module opus_ffi.
I added it to Cargo.toml inside my project directory like this:
[dependencies]
opus_ffi = { path = "opus_ffi" }

for reference, my project folder structure looks like this:
opus_ffi/
  opus/    <-- original C library
  src/
    lib.rs
    wrapper.h
  target/
  build.rs
  Cargo.toml
  Cargo.lock
src/
  api/
     mod.rs
     opus.rs
  lib.rs
build.rs
Cargo.toml  <-- where I declared opus_ffi

I'd like to keep the folder structure the way it is, I'm using flutter_rust_bridge and it requires a very specific folder structure. The only modification to the exact structure I made was adding the opus_ffi folder into the same directory as the higher level src folder.
I'd like to write the bulk of the code for accessing the FFi inside opus.rs. However, when I try and access it:
use opus_ffi;

pub struct Encoder {
    encoder: *mut opus_ffi::OpusEncoder
}
impl Encoder {
    fn new() {}
}

pub struct Decoder {}
impl Decoder {}

I get an error highlighting use opus_ffi with the error
unresolved import `opus_ffi`
no external crate `opus_ffi`

I tried putting extern crate opus_ffi inside mod.rs and that gives this error:
can't find crate for `opus_ffi`
can't find crate

I'm sure that this stems from my lack of understand on Rust's module system – where am I going wrong here?
Edit: Here are both Cargo.toml files and the results of cargo check:
opus_ffi/Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "opus_ffi"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib", "cdylib"]

[target.'cfg(any(target_os = "ios", target_os = "macos"))'.dependencies]
core-foundation = "0.9"

[target.'cfg(target_os = "android")'.dependencies]
jni = "0.19"

[dependencies]
cmake = "0.1.50"
libc = "0.2.155"
pkg-config = "0.3.30"

[build-dependencies]
bindgen = "0.69.4"
cc = "1.1.7"

and the root Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "rust_lib_flutter_rust_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "staticlib"]

[dependencies]
cpal = "0.15.3"
opus_ffi = { path = "opus_ffi" }
flutter_rust_bridge = "=2.1.0"

and finally, the results of cargo check:
zacharyhaslam@MacBook-Air-208 rust % cargo check
warning: opus_ffi@0.1.0: opus/src/repacketizer.c:305:11: warning: unused variable 'ret' [-Wunused-variable]
warning: opus_ffi@0.1.0:       int ret = opus_packet_extensions_generate(&data[ext_begin], ext_len, all_extensions, ext_count, 0);
warning: opus_ffi@0.1.0:           ^
warning: opus_ffi@0.1.0: 1 warning generated.
warning: unexpected `cfg` condition value: `test`
 --> build.rs:4:15
  |
4 |     #[cfg(not(feature = "test"))]
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: remove the condition
  |
  = note: no expected values for `feature`
  = help: consider adding `test` as a feature in `Cargo.toml`
  = note: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/check-cfg/cargo-specifics.html> for more information about checking conditional configuration
  = note: `#[warn(unexpected_cfgs)]` on by default

warning: `rust_lib_flutter_rust_test` (build script) generated 1 warning
    Checking rust_lib_flutter_rust_test v0.1.0 (/Users/zacharyhaslam/FlutterApplications/flutter_rust_test/rust)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `opus_ffi`
 --> src/api/opus.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use opus_ffi;
  |     ^^^^^^^^ no external crate `opus_ffi`
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
warning: `rust_lib_flutter_rust_test` (lib) generated 10 warnings
error: could not compile `rust_lib_flutter_rust_test` (lib) due to 1 previous error; 10 warnings emitted

the other 10 warnings emitted are all just reminders of unused variables in other places in the project, I removed them for clarity.

How are you compiling the project?

What's in opus_ffi/Cargo.toml?

Aside: if opus_ffi is a thin wrapper around opus that just makes the original C functions available then the established naming convention would suggest the name opus_sys instead. There is also a crate that does this already audiopus_sys

@ChayimFriedman I'm intending for it to be compiled to an Android/iOS device. I made sure to add those targets to rustup but other than that I'm not entirely sure what I would need to do for this to compile. I've been using flutter_rust_bridge for this

@cafce25 thanks for the suggestion. I've got bindgen and cc as build dependencies for the FFI stuff and a bunch of other random nonsense. take a look here if you'd like. I also decided to make this crate because audiopus_sys doesn't support android/ios, but I haven't figured out how to to this quite yet

@ChayimFriedman after double checking compiler output after trying to push to a physical device, on Android the command is this:
External Command: rustup "run" "stable" "cargo" "build" "--manifest-path" "/Users/zacharyhaslam/FlutterApplications/flutter_rust_test/rust/Cargo.toml" "-p" "rust_lib_flutter_rust_test" "--target" "aarch64-linux-android" "--target-dir" "/Users/zacharyhaslam/FlutterApplications/flutter_rust_test/build/rust_lib_flutter_rust_test/build"
the ios rustup command doesn't show in the build output error, but I am sure that it is similar.

Please edit your question to include the contents of both Cargo.tomls and the full error output from running cargo check. All of those things may contain key information to what is going wrong.

@KevinReid done. thanks for the reminder

Looks like your problem may be solved by How do I import a crate-type = "cdylib" library? The solution being to add "lib" to the crate-type array in order to use it as a Cargo dependency.

@kmdreko that was it - after adding lib then it works. great find on that post. thank you very much!
